# Send to all clients

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

Im in need of your help :D
So, I'm trying to build a simple Java Multi Socket Server. I sarted with this Code here: http://www.kieser.net/linux/java_server.html and modifyed it a bit. Works well, but I need to send the messages back to all client, not only to the one, who sended. 
Heres my modifyed code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    private static int port=4444, maxConnections=0;
    private static Date date = new Date();

    // Listen for incoming connections and handle them
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        System.out.println("[Notice][" + date.toString() + "] - Server started!");
        try{
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket server;

            while((i++ < maxConnections) || (maxConnections == 0)){
                server = listener.accept();
                doComms conn_c= new doComms(server);
                Thread t = new Thread(conn_c);
                System.out.println("[Notice][" + date.toString() + "] - Client connected! ID: " + i);
                t.start();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class doComms implements Runnable {
    private Socket server;
    private String line;

    private static Date date = new Date();

    doComms(Socket server) {
        this.server=server;
    }

    public void run () {

        try {
            // Get input from the client
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (server.getInputStream());
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());

            while((line = in.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("exit")) {
                out.println("Somebody says: " + line);
                log("Message: " + line, 0);
            }
            log("Server closed", 0);
            server.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void log(String msg, int lvl)
    {
        if(lvl == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("[Notice][" + date.toString() + "] - " + msg);
        }else if(lvl == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("[Warn][" + date.toString() + "] - " + msg);
        }else if(lvl == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("[Error][" + date.toString() + "] - " + msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's not much to do, but I don't get it :D
Thanks for you help!

//Edit

Here is the working Code for now, I'm not sure: Should I use Multicast Sockets? Do they have better performance?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    private static int port=4444, maxConnections=0;
    private static Date date = new Date();

    // Listen for incoming connections and handle them
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        System.out.println("[Notice][" + date.toString() + "] - Server started!");
        try{
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket server;

            while((i++ < maxConnections) || (maxConnections == 0)){
                server = listener.accept();
                doComms conn_c= new doComms(server, i -1);
                Thread t = new Thread(conn_c);
                System.out.println("[Notice][" + date.toString() + "] - Client connected! ID: " + i);
                t.start();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("[Error][" + date.toString() + "] - " + ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class doComms implements Runnable {
    private Socket server;
    private String line;

    private int client_id;
    private boolean cmd = false;

    private DataInputStream in;
    private PrintStream out;

    private static ArrayList<doComms> clients = new ArrayList<doComms>(); 

    private static Date date = new Date();

    doComms(Socket server, int id) {
        this.server = server;
        this.client_id = id;
        clients.add(this);
    }

    public void run () {

        try {
            // Get input from the client
            in = new DataInputStream (server.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());

            while((line = in.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("shutdown") && !line.equals("exit")) {
                send_toAll(line, this.client_id);
                log("Message: " + line, 0);
            }

            if(line.equals("shutdown"))
            {
                log("Got shutdown, going down now!", 0);
                log("Calling to exit...", 0);

                send_toAll("Going down in 5sec! See you!", this.client_id);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                log("Exiting! See you!", 0);
                System.exit(0);
            }

            exit();

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ioe) {
            log("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe, 2);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void exit()
    {
        log("Client with ID: " + this.client_id + " disconnected.", 0);
        clients.remove(this.client_id);

        try {

            this.in.close();
            this.out.close();
            this.server.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe, 2);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void send_toAll(String msg, int id)
    {
        for (int i =0; i < clients.size(); i++)
        {
            clients.get(i).send(msg, id);
        }
    }

    void send(String msg, int id)
    {
        out.println("Somebody(ID: " + id + ") says: " + msg);
    }

    void log(String msg, int lvl)
    {
        if(lvl == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("[Notice][" + date.toString() + "] - " + msg);
        }else if(lvl == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("[Warn][" + date.toString() + "] - " + msg);
        }else if(lvl == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("[Error][" + date.toString() + "] - " + msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to keep track of all your instances of doComm. Here is sample solution:

1. add a `static` field with some `Collection` (for example `ArrayList`) in `doComms` class
2. in constructor of `doComm` add `this` to that static collection
3. move code for sending message (`out.println`) to a separate method in `doComm`
4. add some method to `doComm` that would accept a `String` argument and then iterate through the static collection of `doComm` instances and invoke the new method for sending a message

I hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

javadeveloper's answer  will achieve what you want to do but don't forget to remove the doComm reference once you close the socket.

However it sounds like what you need is a multicast socket. see [Multicast Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html)

Comment: Sorry for responding late.Depends on what you mean by performance.If the intention of the application is a P2P type application the what you have should suffice however if what you are doing is a group type app the a I would use a multicast socket.see [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html)